# More versions Alamofire in project and framework

Tags: swift, alamofire

I use Alamofire 5.0.2.
IngenicoConnectKit wants to install Alamofire 4.9.1 version.
It can be set in Podfile:
Alamofire 5.0.2 for the project and Alamofire 4.9.1 for IngenicoConnectKit?
After installing IngenicoConnectKit remove Alamofire from the framework and modify the IngenicoConnectKit framework to the new Alamofire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you'd essentially have to fork `IngenicoConnectKit`, update the dependency and then build it yourself.

You'd probably also have to modify your fork of IngenicoConnectKit to support Alamofire 5, as it has [a number of breaking changes](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%205.0%20Migration%20Guide.md).